# VBA - Proctecting but allowing copying to other sheets

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection, copying

I have the code below, where i want to protect almost everything and it Works fine, but i want to modify it, where the user is allowed to run a makro that copies to another sheet. If i run the macro to a protected sheet it cames up it an error.

I hope, that you Guys can help and thank you before handed :)

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each ws In Sheets

        With ws
            .Unprotect Password:="MKM"
            .Protect Password:="MKM", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
            .EnableOutlining = True
        End With

    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This protects each sheet on workbook open. You want the macro that actually does the copying to unlock the relevant sheet and lock it again at the end.

Comment: I want it protect all sheets - What should i do, if i want it to be unprotected and then protected Again, only when i use the macro to copy over? You the code from befor, sir - That is the one i want to use :)

Comment: It Works fine now, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it Again, and it Works perfectly, just as it is - I dont know what caused it, but it Works perfectly :)